# Maven not running cucumber tests with mvn clean verify

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, bdd, acceptance-testing

I have a single-module Maven application but `mvn clean verify` would only run the tests below `domain` and not under `acceptance` in the following test package structure:

```
com->  x -> acceptance -> AcceptanceTests.java

com->  x -> domain -> <REST_OF_TESTS>
```

In another words, `mvn clean verify` only runs `<REST_OF_TESTS>`.

Here's my `AcceptanceTests.java`, which runs perfectly from IntelliJ IDEA:

```
package com.x.acceptance;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources", plugin = {"pretty"})
public class AcceptanceTests { }
```

My final goal is to run all tests from terminal with `mvn clean verify` at a Makefile level, but the Cucumber tests won't run. Could you please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When using `mvn verify` Failsafe is used and test names should follow these conventions:

> https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html
> Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests Inclusions
>
> By default, the Failsafe Plugin will automatically include all test
> classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> ```
> "**/IT*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "IT".
> "**/*IT.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "IT".
> "**/*ITCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "ITCase".
> ```
>
> If the test classes do not follow any of these naming conventions,
> then configure Failsafe Plugin and specify the tests you want to
> include.

When using `mvn test` Surefire is used and test names should follow these conventions:

> https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html
> Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests Inclusions
>
> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
> classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> ```
> "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
> "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
> "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
> "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
> ```
>
> If the test classes do not follow any of these naming conventions,
> then configure Surefire Plugin and specify the tests you want to
> include.

So read your class name *very* carefully.
If that doesn't help, try the tutorial and spot the differences with your project.

https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/